# AngularJS view not updating when model changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Firstly, I looked other questions in stackoverflow about it and I readed many answers but still I can't solved my problem.

I'm using Angular Material and I have trouble with view & model synchronization.

This is my controller code:

```
$scope.getQuestionByDateRange = function (range) {
     QuestionService.getQuestions(1, 'week', 10, function (response) {
         $scope.questions = response.data;
     })
}
```

And this is my view code:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="question in questions">{{question.title}}<li>
<ul>
```

My view renders the model correctly while I update `$scope.questions` variable in the controller.

But when I update again `$scope.questions`: my model gets updated (*I can see that changes in console logs*) but the view don't.

I research about it and I found solutions like `$scope.$apply`, `$scope.$digest`, `$scope.$evalAsync` but couldn't solve my problem.

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you supply more code or a fiddle that lets us see your problem?

Comment: Are you setting questions to a new array or pushing a new element into the existing array?

Comment: @DaveBush I pushing new elements to the existing array.

Comment: What does the code for QuestionService look like? If your callback is being triggered from inside angular code then it should all work, but if your doing something non-angular to trigger the callback that could be the problem.

Comment: You answered my either/or question with a yes, so I still don't know what you are doing.

Comment: @DaveBush I updated my answer, sorry.

Comment: @Duncan my QuestionService working correctly and like a said above my questions object updated correctly. My problem is can't update the view correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the entire object is being replaced (so it looses it's binding to the view).

I would instead of replacing the entire object; just replace it's elements.

```
$scope.questions = $scope.questions || []; 
$scope.getQuestionByDateRange = function (range) {
 QuestionService.getQuestions(1, 'week', 10, function (response) {
     $scope.questions.length=0; // Reset the array
     $scope.questions.push.apply($scope.questions, response.data);
 })
}
```

Comment: This is what I've been TRYING to ask about.  And this is the right answer if he's not reusing the same array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with $watch method :

```
$scope.$watch('questions', function(){
  $scope.getQuestionByDateRange(range);
});
```

$watch method is triggered each time the $scope.question is modified

Comment: That's a hack that shouldn't be needed

Comment: It will cause an infinite loop of calling of $scope.getQuestionByDateRange

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is you're replacing the entire array, which seems to cause issues with Angular.

```html
$scope.getQuestionByDateRange = function (range) {
     QuestionService.getQuestions(1, 'week', 10, function (response) {
         $scope.questions.push.apply($scope.questions, response.data);
     });
}
```